# Android using tasker to send parcelable bundle in intent

Tags: android-intent, parcelable, tasker

I'm finding it hard in using tasker to send an intent which must contain a parcelable bundle.  I have found a lot of examples in java codes, but to have it done in tasker appears to be quite complicated.

Has anyone tried this and could share some examples?

I could use tasker's java functions to create a parcel, but do not know how to send it in a bundle (which can accept parcelable but not parcel).  I've seen java codes using "implements" and "createFromParcel" but don't know how to do it with tasker.  I'm pretty sure tasker can do it since according to its guide (https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/intents.html), it can send intent with bundle (parcelable).  I just don't know how to create this parcelable object first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I've posted a similar question in reddit tasker forum.  https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/rek590/how_to_send_parcelable_bundle_in_intent/   and according to the comments, I guess this is not possible using tasker alone.

Answer (score 0):

In Tasker it would be impracticable to use something like this, at the moment you would need to look for some inner class in which inherits Parcelable from Tasker and create an action in Code > Java Function and add the values ​​of this object and check if it works on sendIntent